# find items whitch has 2 associations (together) using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I've got the database with 3 tables:

```
product (id, name, price, ...)
product_option (id, product_id, option_id)
option (id, value)
```

products have many options

For example I need to find a product with option A **and** option B and not a product with just an option A.

I'm using somethink like this:

```
select * from product
left join product_option on product_option.product_id = product_id

where product_option.option_id in (1,2,3) 
and product_option.option_id in (4)
group by product.id
```

Of course the result is always empty.
I need those products with option_id **(1 or 2 or 3) and 4**

How can I do that?

Comment: So product option should be (1,2,3) or single (4)?

Comment: product options should be (1 or 2 or 3) and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you want two difrent matches, you need to join the product_option twise

```
select * from product
left join product_option AS po1 on product_option.product_id = product_id
left join product_option AS po2 on product_option.product_id = product_id

where po1.option_id in (1,2,3) 
and po2.option_id in (4)
group by product.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from product as p
inner join (product_option as po, product_option as po2)
on p.product_id=po.product_id and p.product_id=po2.product_id
where po.option_id=4 and po2.option_id in(1,2,3)
group by p.product_id;
```

Comment: 1. result is empty. 2. I cannot change in(1,2,3) and in(4) into in(1,2,3,4)

Comment: lol ... simply you don't have product full-fill the condition?

Comment: i have products (around 1 266) but, yes, not any fulfill your condition becouse this condition is different. I don't need products with all the options. I just need a product with option (1 or 2 or 3) and option 4. But thanks for presenting nice trick

Comment: my bad, misunderstanding the question

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE
(option_id IN (1,2) AND option_id NOT IN (3,4)) 
OR   
(option_id IN (4) AND option_id NOT IN (1,2,3))
```

Not sure I got combination pairs right so hope you got the idea

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM product p
 WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
          FROM product_option
         WHERE product_id = p.id
           AND option_id in (1, 2, 3)
       )
   AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
          FROM product_option
         WHERE product_id = p.id
           AND option_id = 4
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't set up your tables on my own DB, but I've done something similar recently. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM product, product_option AS PO1, product_option AS PO2
WHERE product.id = PO1.product_id
  AND product.id = PO2.product_id
  AND PO1.option_id IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND PO2.option_id = 4;
```

Comment: I think this one works as well. it's similar to @Puggan Se solution